# How can I use FF Nikon lenses on the Sony E-mount A7 with full function (AF, etc.)?

Tags: nikon, sony, lens-mount, lens-adapter

I have a complete set of lenses for Nikon FF.

I'm thinking about getting a Sony A7-family camera. What would be my best bet to get the compatibility between them AND retaining AF, exposure, etc.

Everything I found, metabones included only allows mount compatibility but no electronics !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: I'm guessing itis going to haqppen if it hasn't already. The A7RII has shaken the market up and while it is too dear at present, it or something similar will be half the price in the short to medium term.  (say 2 years or less). That doesn't help you NOW but also the A7 family is producing new models at an astounding rate. Usually "buy it and enjoy it" is good advice but in this case the range is so dynamic that an small delay has a fair chance of paying dividends. Imagine eg an A7SII with stabilisation and onboard 4K recording and silent mode and ... (all as per A7RII).

Comment: @PhilipKendall Not really a duplicate, since the answers on that one presuppose non-communicating adapters. There's no information on communicating adapters, like those from Metabones. And the only question we do have (http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/53110/how-good-are-the-ef-mount-to-e-mount-adapters) is about adapting Canon EOS to FF Sony E.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been reported that autofocus adapters for Nikon lenses are in development but none have been released so far.

If you are willing to focus manually and give up luxuries such as aperture control from the camera body and EXIF lens information, then you can have a reasonable experience shooting Nikon lenses on Sony A7. But if you want more than you would be best advised to wait.